# written 2 different library(dll) in c++. when I am accessing both dll in third library, got redefinition error

Tags: c++11

I have written 2 different library(dll) in c++. Now I am accessing both dll in third library.

But in both dll have same enum with same name. When I am accessing both dll in third dll. the enum is conflicting and got error as "error c2365: redifinition; previous definition was 'enumerator'.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

If your question is "*how do I fix this problem?*", there are a couple of solutions:

1. First you can have different names for scoped the enums: `enum class en1 {...}` in DLL1 and `enum class en2 {...}` in DLL2.
2. You can put these enumerations (scoped or not) in different namespaces but with the same name: `namespace ns1 { enum en1 {...} }` in DLL1 and `namespace ns2 { enum en1 {...} }`.

I am sure there are many more solutions.